# How to change the background of the webpage, when changing sub-menu?

Tags: php, css, html

I'm teaching myself php/html/css and am stuck on how to change the background of a page for each subpage.

Example:

- when in main page, if I press in "header > contacts" the background would change to a new image.

I tried in css but it doesn't change the whole page image, since what I'm changing is in `<section>` part.

Webpage of training (http://kamiexp.co.nf)

Comment: In JavaScript `YOURELEMENT.style.background = "..."`

Comment: you have changed your question from changing the background color of an element to adding an image, a better approach would be creating a new question asking for your new requirements instead of changing the whole question.

Answer (score 2):

You need Javascript to achieve that. Given the following html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    some content
  </header>
  <button id="toggleColor">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Simply create another file in the same directory called `script.js` and add this code.

```
(function($){

  var $toggle = $('#toggleColor');
  var $header = $('header');

  $toggle.click(function(){

    $header.css('background', 'red');

  });
})(jQuery);
```

when the button with id `toggleColor` is clicked, `header` element will change color. To learn how Jquery works I'd recommend you started here [Jquery tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

You may also want to `toggleClass`. To do this just create a css rule like this one `.red{background:red;}` then simply do `$header.toggleClass('red')`. I've updated the Demo link.

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/yotoba/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: i undestand jquery a bit, but what you said makes me to make a botton that i already have made and defined. 
In the webpage i defined has training, you can see the background spining has slideshow, made it in javascript. now, what i want, is for each Tag (example #visao) the background image change. 

i was able to change that but since each tag is under <section> the background image don't fill the whole page, just the <section> part.

thank you for your fast aswer.

Comment: This same code would work with any button, you just need to update the `id` name.

Answer (score 1):

here is my approach:

**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/8of8L2hs/1/)**

**Idea:**

Put class name in menu link

Create an array of background image menu_bg with menu class index.

when click on menu link, get class name and get background image name by class name index and set that background image .

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  $("body").css("background-image","url(http://www.nshorephoto.com/greenscreen/fotolia_5650339_xxl_std.jpg)");
   
  var menu_bg = [];
 menu_bg['Empresa_bg'] ='http://www.nshorephoto.com/greenscreen/fotolia_5650339_xxl_std.jpg';
 menu_bg['Missao_bg'] ='http://orig15.deviantart.net/1c5c/f/2009/109/0/5/sample_background_5_by_hiagain69.jpg';
 menu_bg['Valores_bg'] ='http://image.slidesharecdn.com/sonicsamplebluebackground-121213031816-phpapp01/95/sonic-sample-blue-background-1-638.jpg?cb=1355390411';
 menu_bg['Visao_bg'] ='http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/common/images/backgrounds/green.jpg ';
 menu_bg['Projectos_bg'] ='http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/common/images/backgrounds/orange.jpg';
 menu_bg['Contactos_bg'] ='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e0/90/af/e090af3fff9fbccdb460019c1c6e3594.jpg';

 var menu_class;
 var bg_color;
 var bg_img;

 $("ul li a").on("click", function (e){ 
  menu_class = $(this).attr('class');
  bg_img = menu_bg[menu_class];
  $("body").css("background-image","url("+bg_img+")");
  //e.preventDefault();   
 });
 
});
```

```css
#menu
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#menu ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#menu ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#menu ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#menu ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#menu ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#menu ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#menu ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#menu ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#menu ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
 <ul class="sf-js-enabled">
  <li class="with_ul active">
   <a href="#!/empresa" class="Empresa_bg" style="color: rgb(50, 74, 241);">Empresa</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#!/missao" class="Missao_bg" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Missão</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#!/valores" class="Valores_bg" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Valores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/visao" class="Visao_bg" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Visão</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/projectos" class="Projectos_bg" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Projectos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!/contacts" class="Contactos_bg" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Contactos</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: while your code does what i wanted, but, the menus now only change the background and dont progress in the page. argh... some times i think i'm moving backwards instead foward lol.
what part in .js i do change this?

Comment: bro you have to remove e.preventDefault(); then it will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb for anything dynamic that happens on a page without a refresh, for all but the simplest of actions (the exceptions being css based - animation, hover, etc) you will need javascript.

Forget using JQuery, the fact that it uses the sizzle engine to parse the DOM over and over again instead of using DOM caching made it obsolete years ago which is why modern frameworks (foundation6 and i suspect bootstrap) will abandon it now that IE support doesnt have to be as comprehensive with the release of windows10 and edge.

The best solution here would be to either use vanilla javascript or a library with 2-way-databinding capability.

If you are looking for a way to code modular vanilla Javascript i highly recommend watching the following [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f).

As for libraries you should research and choose for yourself as there are quite a few available, however my own recommendation would be vueJS.